# Which preposition do you use: at/in/on + job?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I wonder what preposition should be used in the following example:

What were you responsible for **at/on/in you previous job**?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a simple answer to your question.  A prospective employer interviewing you would ask:   "What do you do in your previous job?".  The use of prepositions, however is one of the subtleties that make English difficult.  Try looking up 'in' in the Cambridge dictionary (online):  you will see that the entry for 'in' goes on forever, as do the entries for 'at' and 'on'.  Look at them carefully and you will learn a lot:  I did!

Comment: *What were you responsible for* is usually understood as *For what disasters were you to blame*. The construction is "What were your responsibilities in your last job?"